# Объясните работу GC в конкретном случае

Tags: c#, async-await, сборщик-мусора

Есть вот такой код:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Subject>> TryReadAllAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using DataContext db = new DataContext(_connectionString);
        return await Task.Run(() => db.GetTable<Subject>().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

И есть класс, который в конструкторе инициализирует коллекцию вот так:

```
public SomeClass
{
     SomeClass()
     {
         Subjects = Task.Run(async () => await DaoFactory.GetDaoSubject().TryReadAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;
     }
    
     public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Далее к `Subjects` идет обращение много где(и нигде не вызывается Dispose() явным образом).

В чем, собственно, вопрос:

если здесь `return await Task.Run(() => db.GetTable<Subject>().ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);` убрать `.ToList()`, то после некоторого кол-ва обращений к `Subjects` для него где-то вызовется `Dispose()` неявным образом, и я на это не смог повлиять, пока не нашел решение через добавление `.ToList()`.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так?

Comment: `Subjects = DaoFactory.GetDaoSubject().TryReadAllAsync().Result;` - по-моему, код в конструкторе можно сократить так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не будет ли блокировки основного потока,если я сделаю .Result?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, блокировка и сейчас есть.

Comment: [Async OOP 2: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, вы правы, перечитал вашу ссылку и ещё msdn, почему-то решил,что запуская таск асинхронно, даже поставив .Result, не будет блокировки потока... А не подскажите, как лучше сделать так,чтобы не было этой блокировки?

Comment: Никогда не использовать `Result` и `Wait()`. Всегда использовать ожидание через `await` (или в методах типа `WhenAll`)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а если в интерфейсе, объявляющим этот метод, нет async, он появляется только при реализации. И получается так, что я не могу использовать await.

Comment: Почему не можете? Вон допустим [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AOvY3P), в интерфейсе `Task`, при реализации получает `async` и внутри себя успешно использует `await`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня, видимо, что-то не так, потому что код практически 1 в 1 с вашим пример и я почему-то вижу предупреждение на этапе компиляции о том,что await нельзя использовать, потому что в вызываемом методе нет async, а он то есть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, стоп,не заметил,что у вас main async. А конструктор нельзя сделать таковым. Значит нужно делать отдельно по async методу для каждого ресурса и вызвать через await в конструкторе,если я правильно понимаю

Comment: У вас вопрос про интерфейс был, а не про то, как запускать уже имеющийся метод. Я вам сказал, что интерфейс для вас не должен быть помехой в этом плане. Касательно запуска в конструкторе асинхронной задачи - это по сути плохо. Конструктор, это место, где собирается ваш класс, почему он должен запускать какую-то логику? Сделайте `public async Task Run() {}` например, пропишите в нем все необходимое и запускайте из стартовой точки приложения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за подсказку, я лучше задам на этот счёт отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вам вон выше ссылку дали про это как раз, там и сказано про то, как инициализировать объект с async логикой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using DataContext db = ...` - что делает `using`?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: так а как влияет на это .ToList()? Почему он продлевает срок жизни? using я знаю как работает.

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP `ToList()` - отсоединяет данные от базы, вычитывая их в память.

Comment: точно, я идиот, спасибо.